# Graph between potential barrier and width of depleted region in a circuit

Tags: semiconductor-physics

these are some graphs for the relation between barrier potential and distance in a pn junction under

1. no biasing
2. reverse biasing
3. forward biasing

[image]

my problem with these graphs is that they all seem to show the same width of depletion region but $\frac{dv}{dx}$ of each graph changes.shouldnt the graphs be such that the slopes of all 3 curves remains same while the width of depletion region change bringing about the effective change in barrier hieght(barrier potential).

Comment: If dopant concentrations are constant (and the same on each side), no. Differing concentrations (p vs n) will yield different slopes on each side of the junction.

Comment: ohk that makes sense